# How can I handle DatePicker date change?

Tags: maui, maui-community-toolkit

I my .Net MAUI app, I use CommunityToolkit.mvvm. I have a DatePicker, and I cannot figure out how to handle the selected date change in a ViewModel command.

Here is my xaml:

```xml
<DatePicker
        Date = "{Binding AppointmentDate, Mode=TwoWay}"
        Margin="10" 
        TextColor="{Binding AppointmentDate, Converter={StaticResource NullDateTimeToColorConverter}}" >
    <DatePicker.Behaviors>
        <toolkit:EventToCommandBehavior
            EventName = "DateSelected"
            Command="{Binding AppointmentDateChangedCommand}" 
            CommandParameter="AppointmentDate" />  
    </DatePicker.Behaviors>
</DatePicker>
```

In ViewModel:

```cs
[ObservableProperty]
[Required(ErrorMessage = "Please select the date of your appointment.")]
private DateTime? _appointmentDate = null;

[RelayCommand]
private void AppointmentDateChanged(object obj)
{
    throw new NotImplementedException();
}
```

This gives me the following error:

> The selected debug engine does not support any code executing on the current thread (e.g. only native runtime code is executing). You can switch to another thread to see if there is compatible code running.

What is wrong?

### Added

This is the full xaml code:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<ContentPage xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/dotnet/2021/maui"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             xmlns:sys="clr-namespace:System;assembly=netstandard"
             xmlns:viewmodel="clr-namespace:LATICRETE_MobileApp.Features.VideoChat"
             xmlns:converters="clr-namespace:LATICRETE_MobileApp.Converters"
             xmlns:toolkit="http://schemas.microsoft.com/dotnet/2022/maui/toolkit"
             x:DataType="viewmodel:AppointmentSchedulePageModel"
             xmlns:local="clr-namespace:LATICRETE_MobileApp.Features.VideoChat"
             x:Class="LATICRETE_MobileApp.Features.VideoChat.AppointmentSchedulePage"

    ControlTemplate="{StaticResource MainPageTemplate}">
    <ContentPage.Resources>
        <converters:NullDateTimeToColorConverter x:Key="NullDateTimeToColorConverter" />

        <Style TargetType="ContentView">
            <Setter Property="VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups">
                <VisualStateGroupList>
                    <VisualStateGroup x:Name="CommonStates">
                        <VisualState x:Name="Normal">
                            <VisualState.Setters>
                                <Setter Property="BackgroundColor"
                                        Value="Transparent" />
                            </VisualState.Setters>
                        </VisualState>
                        <VisualState x:Name="Selected">
                            <VisualState.Setters>
                                <Setter Property="BackgroundColor"
                                        Value="{StaticResource LaticreteColor}" />
                            </VisualState.Setters>
                        </VisualState>
                    </VisualStateGroup>
                </VisualStateGroupList>
            </Setter>
        </Style>
    </ContentPage.Resources>
    <ContentPage.Content>
        <Grid RowDefinitions="*,auto,auto">
            <ScrollView Margin="30" Grid.Row="0">
                <StackLayout>
                    <Label Text="30-min meeting" HorizontalTextAlignment="Center" FontAttributes="Bold" Margin="5"/>
                    <Label Text="Grab some time with us for video call" HorizontalTextAlignment="Center" Margin="5, 5, 5, 15 "/>

                    <Label Text="DATE:" />
                    <DatePicker 
                        x:Name="AppointmentDatePicker"
                        Date="{Binding AppointmentDate, Mode=TwoWay}"                         
                        Margin="10" 
                        TextColor="{Binding AppointmentDate, Converter={StaticResource NullDateTimeToColorConverter}}" >

                    </DatePicker>

                    <toolkit:Expander Margin="0,25">
                        <toolkit:Expander.Header>
                            <StackLayout Orientation="Horizontal">
                                <Label Text="{Binding LabelSelectTimeText}" FontFamily = "FontAwesome" Margin="0,0,25,0" VerticalTextAlignment="Center" />
                                <Label Text="{Binding SelectedTimeDisplay, Mode=TwoWay, StringFormat='{0:hh:mm tt}'}" FontSize="Medium" VerticalTextAlignment="Center" />                                
                            </StackLayout>
                        </toolkit:Expander.Header>
                        <HorizontalStackLayout Padding="10">
                            <CollectionView 
                                Margin="5,5,5,15"
                                ItemSizingStrategy="MeasureAllItems"
                                ItemsSource="{Binding Times, Mode=OneTime}"
                                SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedTime, Mode=TwoWay}"
                                SelectionMode="Single">
                                <CollectionView.ItemsLayout>
                                    <GridItemsLayout Orientation="Vertical" Span="3" />
                                </CollectionView.ItemsLayout>
                                <CollectionView.ItemTemplate>
                                    <DataTemplate>                                      
                                        <ContentView Padding="5" >
                                            <Border
                                                StrokeThickness="1"
                                                StrokeShape="RoundRectangle 10">
                                                <Label 
                                                    Text="{Binding ., StringFormat='{0:hh:mm tt}'}"
                                                    Padding="10"
                                                    FontAttributes="Bold"
                                                    HorizontalTextAlignment="Center"
                                                    BackgroundColor="Transparent"
                                                    TextColor="Black" />
                                            </Border>
                                        </ContentView>
                                    </DataTemplate>
                                </CollectionView.ItemTemplate>
                            </CollectionView>
                        </HorizontalStackLayout>
                    </toolkit:Expander>

                    <Label Text="Phone Number:" />
                    <Entry Placeholder="Add your phone number" VerticalOptions="Center" Text="{Binding CustomerPhone, Mode=TwoWay}" />
                    <Label Text="Notes:" />
                    <Editor x:Name="notes"
                        Placeholder="Add any special requests"
                        Text="{Binding Notes, Mode=TwoWay}"
                        HeightRequest="250" />        
                </StackLayout>
            </ScrollView>
            <StackLayout 
                Grid.Row="1"
                x:Name="Validation" 
                IsVisible="{Binding HasErrors}">
                    <Label Text="Please fix the following errors:" TextColor="Red" Margin="0,0,0,10" />
                    <Label Text="{Binding Errors}" TextColor="Red" />
            </StackLayout>
            <Button
                Grid.Row="2"
                Command="{Binding ScheduleAppointmentCommand}" 
                Text="{Binding ButtonScheduleAppointmentText}" 
                Style="{StaticResource ButtonStyle}" />
        </Grid>
    </ContentPage.Content>
</ContentPage>
```

And code behind:

```cs
public partial class AppointmentSchedulePage : ContentPage
{
    public AppointmentSchedulePage(AppointmentSchedulePageModel pageModel)
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        BindingContext = pageModel;
    }
}
```

Comment: you are already binding `AppointmentDate`, do you actually need to execute some behavior when the date changes?  You could do that in the setter of the property.  If you do stick with the command you should also use a binding expression, not a hardcoded string, for the command parameter.

Comment: @Jason Yes, I have to populate something else based on the date selection. I read that a setter is only for something very simple, isn't that right? Could you please give me a sample of how the binding expression in this context would look?

Comment: I don't think it's ideal to put a LOT of code in a setter, but it's certainly something I've done on occasion.  It wouldn't hurt to try.  The expression should just be `"{Binding AppointmentDate}"`

Comment: @Jason Unfortunately, binding did not fix the problem :(

Comment: what line of code causes the exception?  What does the stack trace show?

Comment: @Jason It has something to do with the breakpoint I place inside of the command code. Without the breakpoint, no error. But I need to be able to debug to continue with my coding.

Comment: have you tried using the setter instead, or Peter's OnChange suggestion?

Comment: @Jason Just tried it, and it gave me the same issue when I have a breakpoint in the setter. Looks like it has something to do with the DatePicker, as it doesn't happen with a button.

Comment: I think you're just going to have to accept that you're not going to be able to use the debugger on this piece of code and move on.

Comment: @Jason I guess so... I will debug using another handler, and when ready, move the code where it belongs... Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are at least two solutions to this. You can Use OnPropertyChanged and use the AppointmentDate you already using, or you can use EventToCommandBehavior. No need to use both.

Using OnPropertyChanged looks like this.
In the ViewModel you have

```cs
[ObservableProperty]
private DateTime _appointmentDate = DateTime.Now;

protected override void OnPropertyChanged(PropertyChangedEventArgs e)
{
    base.OnPropertyChanged(e);

    if (e.PropertyName == nameof(AppointmentDate))
    {
        Debug.WriteLine($"AppointmentDate: {AppointmentDate}");
    }

}
```

And your xaml looks like this:

```xml
<DatePicker Margin="10" Date="{Binding AppointmentDate}" />
```

or you go with

```xml
<DatePicker Margin="10" x:Name="MyDatePicker" Date = "{Binding AppointmentDate}" >
    <DatePicker.Behaviors>
        <toolkit:EventToCommandBehavior
                    Command="{Binding DatePickedCommand}"
                    CommandParameter="{Binding Date, Source={x:Reference MyDatePicker}}"
                    EventName="DateSelected" />
    </DatePicker.Behaviors>
</DatePicker>
```

With a ViewModel like

```cs
public DateTime AppointmentDate { get; } = DateTime.Now;

[RelayCommand]
private async Task DatePicked(DateTime date)
{
    Debug.WriteLine($"AppointmentDate: {date}");
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I am trying your second option, but keep getting the same error: 
No compatible code running on the thread
The selected debug engine does not support any code executing on the current thread (e.g. only native runtime code is executing). You can switch to another thread to see if there is compatible code running.

Comment: This is basic things and should not render those errors. Have you cleaned, rebuilt and built? Try remove, obj and bin catalog. Also please give us your complete view with xaml and codebehind. Have you looked at your debug configuration manager so that all looks good there?

Comment: Is your ViewModel AppointmentSchedulePageModel registered as a singleton or anything else?

Comment: I added the code to my question. You can see the AppointmentSchedulePageModel in the code behind. Yes, I did register it as a singleton: builder.Services.AddSingleton<AppointmentSchedulePageModel>(); And without the breakpoint in the command body there is no such error.

Comment: Do you have any Nuget packages that is not compatible with MAUI? Or any platform services that goes on start? Have you tried to create a new project and see if you get this error with just this view and viewmodel? To rule out that you have problem with debugging in Visual Studio.

Comment: If you look in Setting have you set Tools > Options > Debugging and Enable Just My Code?

Comment: I don't think it is about NuGet package or something. It is not a new app, and I have been working on it for long time. I can debug other commands (on button press) with breakpoints without problems. And yes, Just My Code is set.

Comment: OK, what about make a copy of those files, delete them and make new ones. Copy all the code back. Just for a test....

Comment: This did not fix the issue :(

Comment: Why do you have this: xmlns:sys="clr-namespace:System;assembly=netstandard" ?

Comment: To be honest, I don't remember, must be a leftover. I just removed it, and it did not change anything.

Comment: If you think it is something in the code. You can remove all code and reapply it bit by bit and see where it changes.